# Why don't we update when exploring (making non-greedy moves)?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I was reading [*Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction*](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/) and came upon a method for solving tic-tac-toe.

During this method, the computer trying to learn usually takes the greedy move (the move it thinks will make it most likely to win).

When the computer does not take the greedy move (otherwise known as "exploring"), the authors recommend not having the computer update completely based on the response (it only updates back to that exploration move and no further).

But, in [this project](https://users.auth.gr/kehagiat/Research/GameTheory/12CombBiblio/TicTacToe.pdf) a student found they got better results when using full updating on each move, regardless if it was greedy or exploratory.

The authors leave it as an exercise that I do not know the answer to.

Why is it that we don't update fully when exploring? What good does it do?

Comment: It's learning two different value functions. One is learning the value function of the policy that you eventually want to follow whereas the other is learning the value function of your policy with exploration.

Comment: I think I understand. Thanks! In other words, the policy and probabilities represent the probability that that spot is a good one to choose if you are always choosing the best option later on. It wouldn't make much sense to have a policy that the spot is a good one based on choosing bad options later on, so that makes sense.

Comment: @DaVinci If you want to add that as an answer, I'll upvote and accept (at least until a better one comes along)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's learning two different value functions. One is learning the value function of the policy that you eventually want to follow whereas the other is learning the value function of your policy with exploration. The reason why it might work better to learn the second one in some cases is that the added noise may make it more robust. However, in the end you would rather want to learn the actual value function.